# Problem extract data file json from Imgur API

Tags: javascript, api, imgur

I have a problem to extract a data from a json file created from a GET from Imgur API.

That is the json :

`{
            "id": "ADgvagy",
            "title": "This game is so much fun ",
            ...
            "include_album_ads": false,
            "images": [
                {
                    "id": "VLeeDfj",
                    ...
                    "in_gallery": false,
                    "link": "https://i.imgur.com/VLeeDfj.mp4",
                    "mp4_size": 2707912,
                    "mp4": "https://i.imgur.com/VLeeDfj.mp4",
                    "gifv": "https://i.imgur.com/VLeeDfj.gifv",
                    "hls": "https://i.imgur.com/VLeeDfj.m3u8",
                    "processing": {
                        "status": "completed"
                    },
                    "comment_count": null,
                    ...
                    "score": null
                }
            ]
        },`

I have no problem to extract the ***title*** data when I do ***this.props.post.title***.

I tried :
***this.props.post.images.link*** -> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.post.images.link')

***this.props.post.images[0].link*** -> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.post.images[0]')

Thanks for your time.

Comment: does the json look like ```[{<imgur stuff>}, {<imgur stuff>}, ...]```?
if so, try ```this.props.post[0].images[0].link```, or try logging after every . (dot) to your console.

Comment: ```console.log(this.props);```, ```console.log(this.porps.post);```, ```console.log(this.props[0]);```, ```console.log(this.props[0].post);```

Comment: The example json is from a `console.log(this.props.post)`.
So `console.log(this.props[0])` isn't working

Comment: seems like you're doing something wrong. there's a comma at the end of JSON in your post, so it's clearly in an array, try checking if ``props`` or ``props.post`` is an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. The correct way is to do `this.props.post["images"][0].link`